# Android how can we design a menu for a list view similar to that of android 4.1 ICS?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.1-eclair

I am new to Android and I am developing an app in android 2.1. The UI has a list view in it and on focusing the list shows a dropdown menu as in this image:

http://developer.android.com/design/media/app_structure_gmail.png

How can I design a menu for a list view similar to this?

Comment: [Action Bar Drop-down Navigation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) Use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get you , even your link is not working. Might be you are talking about Expandable list like [this](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html).

Look at above link.